# Check out NLP Discussions on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I’m Berthold, a community manager who works primarily with the Stack Overflow site. On SO, we’ve just launched an [experimental “Discussions” feature](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426107/discussions-experiment-launching-on-nlp-collective) within the [NLP (Natural Language Processing) Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/nlp).

Discussions is a step into subjective content for Stack Overflow, and NLP is a space that has some notable overlap with the topic of this site. So I am posting here for a few reasons:

To invite and encourage your participation in the Discussions space of the NLP Collective on Stack Overflow. There is no rep requirement to post or reply there, and the guidelines allow for a wide range of post types.
To invite your input on how this community has handled subjective content about natural language processing and related topics here on this site. What has worked well, and what have you struggled with?
To invite your ongoing collaboration around the evolution of the Discussions concept in general. As venues for building subcommuntiy around a specific topic, both Collectives and Discussions share goals with the Data Science Stack Exchange community. We’d love to hear your thoughts about the potential benefits, risks, and opportunities that you see ahead.

Feel free to provide input on this post, or elsewhere on this Meta site, or on Meta Stack Overflow – wherever you feel is most appropriate. Please draw staff attention to your post if you make a new one here.

#### Further reading

In addition to [the announcement about Discussions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426107/discussions-experiment-launching-on-nlp-collective) on Meta Stack Overflow, there is [another post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426143/the-user-research-behind-discussions) that takes a deeper dive into the research behind the development of Discussions. For more information about the NLP Collective, read [this MSO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425530/new-collective-nlp-scope-community-and-questions).